# How to write sigtstp handler to go back to the main loop in my self-implemented shell after ctrl+z?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, signals

In my self-made shell, if I press 'ctrl+z' during a foreground process, such as

`sleep 40`

then my program stops there even if I press 'ctrl+c'. I want to know how to implement the SIGTSTP handler so that after control+z it can go back to the main loop to accept next command.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing on line#42.

Answer (score 1):

Your process doesn't receive `SIGTSTP`, when the child stops, you receive `SIGCHLD`.  The description of `SIGCHLD` is:

> Child process terminated, stopped, or continued

Details may be found in the POSIX documentation at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html

Comment: My process could receive SIGTSP. I installed SIGZTSP by signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstpHanlder); and in my void sigtstpHanlder(int signal), I added a printf to test. Whenever I press 'control+z', this printf does prove that the handler receives the SIGTSP.

Comment: Then you should raise SIGSTOP to the child process so that it pauses, and waitpid will show the status change.